# How do you get two Flask test clients to communicate using Request

Tags: flask, python-requests, pytest

I am new to Flask, and I am trying to learn so I can write pytests for applications I am working on.

In my project, there are two applications that are sometimes communicating; one occasionally sends requests to the other using the 'request' library, and the other sends a response back.

In most of the examples of Flask testing I have seen, it is done by using an application's 'test_client' method. The question I have is on how to get two of these test clients to communicate.

For a toy example, here I have two apps:

flask_app1.py

```
from flask import Flask
import requests

def create_app():

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/send_message/<msg>')
    def send_message(msg):
        response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5001/receive_msg', json={'message': msg})
        print(response.text)
        return "sent:" + response.json()['received']

    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run()
```

flask_app2.py

```
from flask import Flask, request

def create_app():

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/receive_msg', methods=["POST"])
    def receive():
        msg = request.get_json()["message"]
        print(msg)
        return {'received': msg}

    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run(port=5001)
```

Simply, the first app sends a message to the second, which then sends it back to the first.

Now suppose I have the tests:

```
import flask_app1
import flask_app2


def test_two_clients():
    app1 = flask_app1.create_app()
    client1 = app1.test_client()

    app2 = flask_app2.create_app()
    client2 = app2.test_client()

    r = client1.get('/send_message/hello_there')

    assert r.status_code == 200


def test_one_client():
    app1 = flask_app1.create_app()
    client1 = app1.test_client()

    r = client1.get('/send_message/hello_there')

    assert r.status_code == 200
```

The bottom test works when flask_app2 is running in a terminal, but that's not what I want.
I am not sure how to get client1 to communicate with client2

Comment: I'm not completely confident I get what it is exactly you want but from what I gathered here's my take; The two apps will communicate by making requests to each other much like any other apps on the web, so you need to have both running (perhaps on different ports). You can then write tests for each  individually cheking whether the request was successful and the expected response was received.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any pattern to test two Flask applications against each other, without at least running one.

I acknowledge you do not want to run them, but for completeness:

You could spin up some Docker containers, run your applications there, and test them this way. IMHO this makes perfect sense for an end to end test.

As you do not want to do this, you should think about the implementation of your code. There is pattern called **Dependency Injection** - this enables you to test your applications completely self contained.

There is an excellent blog post about this https://www.cosmicpython.com/blog/2020-01-25-testing_external_api_calls.html

Other possibilities are to **mock** the call to the other Flask app or to record its output via https://github.com/kevin1024/vcrpy

I know, this was not the expected answer, but I hope you find something useful.